# Can't ping neighboring router OSPF

Tags: router, ospf, ping

I have set up an OSPF network and I cannot ping from the Edge router to Main Branch. [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Never use an image for text. Just copy the text and paste it into the post using the question using the Preformatted-text option (`[]`). Please edit your question to correct it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems:

The two addresses, `10.1.2.6/30` and `10.1.2.2/30` are in two different networks, but they need to be in the same network for direct router connection (see [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for the specifics).

Next, never use the `ip default-gateway` command on a router the has routing enabled (see [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/46714/8499) for the details).

Also, the Edge router will not form a neighbor on a passive interface.

Comment: If it solved your problem, then you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking fo an answer.